# JUnit failing to make a temporary file when run in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, junit, windows-7-x64

I've just got a new Windows 7 x64 laptop at work and Eclipse is now failing to run JUnit when I try to "batch" run the tests (i.e. right click on the test folder and run as..).  This used to work fine on my Windows XP laptop on the exact same project with the exact same Eclipse.

I looked at the error log and found the following stack trace:

```
java.io.IOException: The system cannot find the path specified
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.createTempFile(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.File.createTempFile(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.junit.launcher.JUnitLaunchConfigurationDelegate.createTestNamesFile(JUnitLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.junit.launcher.JUnitLaunchConfigurationDelegate.collectExecutionArguments(JUnitLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.junit.launcher.JUnitLaunchConfigurationDelegate.launch(JUnitLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:855)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:704)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:1047)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1251)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

I suspect that this is a permissions issue on Windows 7, but having played about with my temp folder, moved Eclipse out of Program Files and killed the virus scanner (I think!), I feel like I am flailing about in the dark a bit.  Has anyone else seen this?

Comment: Please add your test code too.

Comment: Hi willome, there are over 3000 unit tests, so that's not really feasible I'm afraid.  Also, the failure is occurring before any of the test code is actually run.  I should also say that I can go into a particular class and run all the tests in that class successfully.

Comment: Hmm, the plot thickens! I have just tried using a different Eclipse that I nicked off my colleague (still Juno) and that works as expected. It would be great if someone could tell me what might cause this issue, as otherwise I'll need to go get all my plugins again, but at least I do have a way forward.